# Trouble with simple deform on an array

Tags: modeling, modifiers

I'm very new to Blender (and 3D modeling in general), but I have a basic understanding of the interface and some of the principles involved with creating shapes.

I'm attempting to model a character of mine, starting with the "face" area, which contains his mouth. Because his face is round, and ends with these repeating scalloped shapes, I decided to design a segment of his face (scalloped end included):

[image]

And apply an Array modifier to it, set to the number of scallops I figured the character needs, which is about 10.

With a little offset included on the X-axis to create the desired overlap, I then dropped down a circle mesh set to the circumference of the character's body. I then applied a Simple Deform modifier to the scalloped shape, and attempted to bend it 360 degrees, using the circle as the axis. This is where everything breaks:

[image]

It doesn't maintain the shape I'd intended, the scaling is all off, and it doesn't seamlessly connect. I'm really lost as to where I went wrong with this, as I've attempted several different methods that all resulted in my shapes looking wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best way to this is with only array modifier and object offset.
Create a empty at the center and rotate it (36°).
You can still edit the shell and maybe add solidify and subsurf modifier!
[image]

Comment: CandeFan, thanks for the tip. Can I ask which viewport  you're showing on the left side of the image?

Comment: Top ortho. And i used part of a uv Sphere to make it simple. ;)

Comment: Reuse the mesh to make helmet, legs (and arms?)!

Comment: Ah, I see. I'm still struggling to get the array to wrap around correctly, as the results are not what I expect. You pretty much nailed the shape I'm looking for, and yes, I would definitely re-use the array for the legs and helmet :)  Where should I place the origin of the uv sphere part, relative to the origin of the empty?

Comment: Dead center. Make sure no relative or constant offset.

Comment: Excellent, I've got the shape to wrap perfectly, but I'm wondering why it separates once I transform the object/array around the screen? Is there a method you suggest I use to get the object/array to act as one united object without separating?

Comment: I would make a copy (to different layer for use later) and collapse to mesh.
Or you could parent the shell to the empty (select empty last and hit ctrl p) and move the empty. Now it´s bedtime in Sweden. I will check tomorrow. Excuse my English...

Comment: Brilliant, CandeFan. I really appreciate your help! And your English is very good. Cheers!